# Разбить 3 объекта в строку

Tags: javascript

У меня есть переменная `attachments`. 
В ней 3 объекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне разбить эти 3 объекта в **одну строку**, через `"*"`, при помощи js?
То есть примерно вот так должно быть `"Koala.jpg*Lighthouse.jpg*Penguins.jpg"`.

Пробовал через цикл `for`, а потом объединять, что-то все равно не получается.
Благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас массив объектов, перебираем массив и на каждой итерации вытаскиваем свойство `name`

```js
const attachments = [{name: 'koala.jpg'},{name: 'light.jpg'},{name: 'penguins.jpg'}]
const names = attachments.reduce((str, {name}) => str += name, '')
console.log(names)
```

Comment: Благодарю) Действительно помог